# Reactivation of python scripts - Linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I don't understand why my 'for loop' doesn't work correctly. The first argument works fine. If I manually deactivate the second python script, it won't start the script again. Can you assist me here?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/admin/instaTweet

bots=( one.py two.py three.py )
botSize=${#bots[*]}
checkProcessSize=$(ps -e -o comm= | grep screen | wc -l)


echo $(date) >> checkBotsLog.txt
echo "$botSize Bots available" >> checkBotsLog.txt

if [ $botSize -gt $checkProcessSize ]
then
        time=$(date)
        tweet_string="###ALERT### At least one bot is inactive! "$(echo $time)
        python3 tweet.py "$(echo $tweet_string)"
        echo "At least one Bot is inactive" >> checkBotsLog.txt

        for i in $bots; do
                process=$(ps -aux | grep "python $i" | wc -l)

                if [ $process -lt 2 ]
                then
                        screen -d -m python $i
                        echo $i started >>checkBotsLog.txt
                fi
        done
else
        time=$(date)
        tweet_string="All bots are active! "$(echo $time)
        python3 tweet.py "$(echo $tweet_string)"
        echo "Everything fine" >> checkBotsLog.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just figured it out.

I changed:

```
for i in $bots; do...
```

to:

```
for i in ${bots[@]}: do..
```